# Facing problem in toggle method of jquery

Tags: jquery

HI,

I have following html

```
    <div id="LineInfoHeader" class="div_header_inner headertitle align_center defaultheadercolor portlet-header-left-padding default_bottom_border default_border_color"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>Line Item Information</div>
**Edit**

    <div class="div_content_inner" id="Order_header"></div>
```

I am trying to toggle span class and Order_header div.
I am using following code:

```
$(".div_header_inner.ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick").toggle();
}
```

I don't know why its not working.
Please suggest where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance.
[**You can see the problem here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RPEK9/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your selector is off, it's looking for an element with *both* classes `.div_header_inner` *and* `.ui-icon`, rather than one inside the other.  For that you need a space in-between ([the descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/)), like:

```
$(".div_header_inner .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick").toggle();
```

Also, [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) can take multiple classes (space separated), so you can shorten it down to:

```
$(".div_header_inner .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick").toggle();
```

[You can try that version here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RPEK9/5/).  But, it's not immediately clear to me which element you want to [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) at the end, if it's the `<div>` you need to change it around a bit, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RPEK9/6/):

```
$(".div_header_inner").toggle().find(".ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick");
```

[or this](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RPEK9/7/):

```
$(".div_header_inner .ui-icon").toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick ui-icon-plusthick").parent().toggle();
```

Comment: Thanks Nick... Actually I want to toggle the div and class of span.

Comment: @Vivek - In that case the bottom two are options, though this will hide the space (since it's a child), not sure if toggling the class matters so much when that happens :)

Comment: Please see the updated question....Now, I am trying to toggle span class and Order_header div. How to do this.

Comment: @Vivek - this would be the generic solution, so you could have any number in a page: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RPEK9/8/ also, consider `.slideToggle()` instead: http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/RPEK9/9/